# jquery tooltip on form elements style not displayed

Tags: jquery

I implemented tooltips based on [this](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html).
I see tooltip but without style. It seems that what is in style sheet does not work properly.

My code:

**JS**

```
       // select all desired input fields and attach tooltips to them
      $("#edit_foto_form :input").tooltip({
      // place tooltip on the right edge
      position: "center right",
      // a little tweaking of the position
      offset: [-2, 10],
      // use the built-in fadeIn/fadeOut effect
      effect: "fade",
      // custom opacity setting
      opacity: 0.7
      });
```

**CSS**

```
/* simple css-based tooltip */ .tooltip {
    background-color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding:10px 15px;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:12px;

    /* outline radius for mozilla/firefox only */
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <h1 class="top">Update Foto</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="edit_foto_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_foto" />
        <label for="file">Foto:</label>
        <input type="file" name="fotofile" id="fotofile" title="Bitte Foto 100 x 100, größere werden angepasst."><br>
        <span></span>        
        <br />
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Hochladen" />
        <br />
    </form>
</div
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Jquery added to Head section of doco:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src=http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/localization/messages_de.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you include jquery Tools in the HTML?  You should also fix the div end tag, unless that was a copy/paste error.

Comment: Sure '         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
        <script src=http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/localization/messages_de.js"></script>'

Answer (score 0):

Place JS code inside: (document.ready)

> $(function() {
>
> //your JS code
>
> ```
> });
> ```

Comment: http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js this is the link you need.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery tooltip does not seems to be working for `input type="file"`. I used your code and just changed `type="text"`, and it works fine.

You can see the demo here:

[jsfiddle.net/3mhSn/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/3mhSn/10/)

Comment: In your example I see that it works for both. At least in FF. In my case Tooltip is displayed but without css formating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jqueryTools.  You've only included jquery, jquery UI, and jquery validate.  Add this to your HTML

`<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with one function where I put both form validation and tooltip. After creating two separate functions all work fine. Thanks once more for all your tips.